# Coloring edges in python cv2 and C# emgu cv

Tags: python, c#, opencv, emgucv

So I'm trying to reproduce a cool filter I did a while back in C# (emgucv) in Python cv2. Despite my hopes it's not going very smoothly. The programs suppose to highlight edges and color them with a cool looking gradient.

The code in C#:

```
        {
        Image<Gray, byte> gray= imgColored.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        Image<Gray, float> photo_dx = gray.Sobel(1, 0, 3);
        Image<Gray, float> photo_dy = gray.Sobel(0, 1, 3);
        Image<Gray, float> photo_grad = new Image<Gray, float>(gray.Size);
        Image<Gray, float> photo_angle = new Image<Gray, float>(gray.Size);
        CvInvoke.CartToPolar(photo_dx, photo_dy, photo_grad, photo_angle, true);
        Image<Hsv, float> coloredEdges = gray.Convert<Hsv, float>(); 

        for (int j = 0; j < coloredEdges.Cols; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < coloredEdges.Rows; i++)
            {
                Hsv pix = coloredEdges[i, j];

                pix.Hue = photo_angle[i, j].Intensity;
                pix.Satuation = 1;
                pix.Value = photo_grad[i, j].Intensity;

                coloredEdges[i, j] = pix;
            }

        coloredEdges.Save("test.jpg");
       }
```

The code in Python:

```
def LSD_ify(image, mag, angle):
     image = image = image.astype(np.float64)
     height, width, depth = image.shape

     for x in range(0, height):
         for y in range(0, width):
            image[x, y, 0] = angle[x, y]
            image[x, y, 1] = 1
            image[x, y, 2] = mag[x, y]

    return image

def main():
       image = plt.imread(str(sys.argv[1]))
       gray_image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
       g2bgr = cv.cvtColor(gray_image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) #cv2 cant convert gray to HSV directly, so i had to convert back to colored and finally to HSV

       gx = cv.Sobel(gray_image, cv.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = 3)
       gy = cv.Sobel(gray_image, cv.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = 3)

       mag, angle = cv.cartToPolar(gx, gy, angleInDegrees = True)
       hsv_image = cv.cvtColor(g2bgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

       lsd = LSD_ify(hsv_image, mag, angle)

       cv.imwrite("test.jpg", lsd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

The code is mostly identical(i think?), the results they produce however are different.
The input image:
[image]

C# program:
[image]

Python script:
[image]

Does anyone have any insight on what I'd have to do to get identical results in Python? I'm not sure how things work in the background in Python.

Comment: Post your input image also, please

Comment: Check the min an max values of mag and angle and g2bgr

Comment: @fmw42 input image added

Comment: gbgr is 3 channel gray. You cannot convert it to HSV. If you do, you will just get a constant value for all 3 channels of hsv.  Gray is sat=0 and val=128 and hue=0.

Comment: If i convert the original BGR image to HSV, the final result is identical. I don't really know if thats the issue, it's something else and i cant figure what...

Comment: `g2bgr = cv.cvtColor(gray_image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` here you are converting the grayscale image to BGR... However, the resulting image has the same pixel values as the grayscale image, but now it has three channels. Is that what you want?

Comment: @stateMachine Basically, yeah. I forget the original purpose of converting the gray to HSV though... this program is something i initially made 5 years ago for uni

Comment: I think you are simply convert gray to HSV in order to initialize your HSV  channels, since you replace them with mag and angle and constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do in Python/OpenCV. Python HSV hue is limited to range 0 to 180 so your angle needs to be scaled to that range. Similarly the magnitude is greater than 255 and also needs to be scaled to the range 0 to 255.  The saturation you want would be a constant 255. I use Skimage to do the scaling. I have printed out the shape and min and max values at various places to show you these issues.

I believe the process is as follows:

- Read the input
- Convert it to gray
- Get the Sobel x and y derivatives
- Compute the magnitude and angle from the derivatives and scale mag to range 0 to 255 and angle to range 0 to 180
- Merge the angle, the magnitude and the magnitude into a 3 channel image as if HSV with angle first, then the magnitudes.
- Replace the second channel (channel 1) with 255 for the saturation
- Convert this HSV image to BGR as the result
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure as exposure

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('rabbit.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply sobel derivatives
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=3)

print(sobelx.shape, np.amin(sobelx), np.amax(sobelx))
print(sobely.shape, np.amin(sobely), np.amax(sobely))
print("")

# get magnitude and angle
mag, angle = cv2.cartToPolar(sobelx, sobely, angleInDegrees = True)

print(mag.shape, np.amin(mag), np.amax(mag))
print(angle.shape, np.amin(angle), np.amax(angle))
print("")

# normalize mag to range 0 to 255 and angle to range 0 to 180
mag = exposure.rescale_intensity(mag, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
angle = exposure.rescale_intensity(angle, in_range='image', out_range=(0,180)).clip(0,180).astype(np.uint8)

print(mag.shape, np.amin(mag), np.amax(mag))
print(angle.shape, np.amin(angle), np.amax(angle))

# combine channels as if hsv where angle becomes the hue and mag becomes the value. (saturation is not important since it will be replace by 255)
hsv = cv2.merge([angle, mag, mag])
hsv[:,:,1] = 255

# convert hsv to  bgr
result = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('rabbit_color_edges.jpg', result)

# show result
cv2.imshow('result', result)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

**ADDITION**

If I scale the magnitude (or gray) by doubling "out_range":

```
mag = exposure.rescale_intensity(mag, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
```

to

```
mag = exposure.rescale_intensity(mag, in_range='image', out_range=(0,510)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Then I get very close to your result:

[image]

Comment: It is good enough, thank you very much for the help. I'll look this over.

Comment: The main issue I think with your code is your did not scale the results to  8-bit and you did not convert from HSV to BGR

Comment: If you figure out how to modify my answer to make my result conform to your result, please post the correction.

Comment: by the way, the 2nd rescaling line has mag instead of angle, when i changed it i got results closer if not identical to my original post.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo (copy and paste error). I will update my post.

Comment: If I scale the magnitude as follows I get very close to your result:  `mag = exposure.rescale_intensity(mag, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)` to `mag = exposure.rescale_intensity(mag, in_range='image', out_range=(0,360)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Correction: I scale from 255 to 510 rather than 360. See my ADDITION in my answer.

Comment: very good, thank you again, i just have to find a way to up the intensity while maintaining the colors EDIT: ok, doing out_range=(0,4096)).clip(0,255) produces reasonably good results for me.

Comment: You can also change the brightness/contrast of the gray image